Website shows 502 error after several minutes and comes back quickly
I have a NextJS project which was running smoothly until one day it constantly started to show 502 error. We use nginx and pm2 on the server. If you need any more info, please ask!
So here's what we did to troubleshoot the issue.

Checked the codebase locally using npm run dev and npm start: during both the code worked smoothly on localhost and there weren't significant errors or warnings (just a hydration error on npm run dev mode and cookie warnings)
Checked pm2 performance using pm2 logs and pm2 monit: on pm2 monit the restarts count was over 3000 and the uptime was 0/1 secs. So technically the website restarts every second. That's a huge issue but we can't seem to understand why it does so. If you need other information from pm2 monit, feel free to ask! on pm2 logs it showed that the website indeed is restarting very frequently, the process starts, tries to find package.json file from wrong path and then exits with 254 exit code, continuing the process by starting in -fork mode-.
Tried to kill the pm2 process but an unexpected thing happened: the website continued working properly. It's suspicious!
Tried to run without pm2 and using npm start: the issue persisted.

